# to get 1st record with conditions in sql

Tags: sql, group-by, where-clause, multiple-columns

i have table with 100 columns name.
I want to get 1st record of each item with specific conditions

I have column name 
Model_Name( car model name about 7 to 8 different models)

Credit_flag(Y/N)

Private_Offer(Y/N)

Cash_back(some value or blank)

Bonus_cash(some value or blank)

Now If i want to get 1st record for each model

where Credit_flag is equal to yes

where private_offer is equal to yes

where cash_back is equal to some value not blank

where Bonus_cash is equal to some value not blank

[image: Cars]

Comment: Do you have a column with a time-stamp of the record entry? How to distinguish between two records if they both comply with a condition? Please post table structure, sample data, and desired output.

Comment: i added table as image

Comment: @user3348408 is your source an Excel file or did you just dump the data to Excel?  If Excel is not the source then what server software (SQL Server/Oracle/etc) are you using?

Comment: its in excel but I also have the access to the data using MS-SQL where i want to write query and get things done quickly.

Comment: If i can get those records than it will be very easy for me to check whether conditions are applied or not on specific record. if yes then it applied to all with the same conditions. So I want to get 1st record of each model with different conditions. If you can give me only two example of two different condition. For Example Credit flag = Y private offer = Y and cash back = some value and bonus cash = some value get the 1st record of each model with these conditions

Answer (score 0):

You cannot just get the first record, you have to specify how. For eg, if you try to fetch the first record, you may get a different result the next time you run the same query, the reason being sql determines the fastest method to get the rows and implements it, if data size increases, it may use another method. To get the same result everytime, you should do an order by so it knows it has to get the first result after sorting the data.

You can use statement similar to below, too lazy to write the entire thing. But you should get the idea.

```
select Top 1 column1, col2,col3 from table where col1 = 'Y' AND cashBack <> '' order by col1
```

Answer (score 0):

The response by @user1063280 assumes that you want a single row from the table. Your question read to me more like you wanted to first relevant row for each model in the table. If that's what you want, the below query should achieve your goal:

```
DECLARE @Cars TABLE
(
    ID int IDENTITY,
    CreditFlag bit,
    PrivateOfferFlag bit,
    ModelName varchar(3),
    CashBack numeric(19,2),
    BonusCash numeric(19,2),
    TotalSavings AS CashBack + BonusCash
);
INSERT INTO @Cars (CreditFlag, PrivateOfferFlag, ModelName, CashBack, BonusCash) VALUES (0, 1, 'AAA', 750, 750);
INSERT INTO @Cars (CreditFlag, PrivateOfferFlag, ModelName, CashBack, BonusCash) VALUES (0, 1, 'BBB', 750, 750);
INSERT INTO @Cars (CreditFlag, PrivateOfferFlag, ModelName, CashBack, BonusCash) VALUES (0, 1, 'CCC', 2500, 750);
INSERT INTO @Cars (CreditFlag, PrivateOfferFlag, ModelName, CashBack, BonusCash) VALUES (1, 1, 'DDD', 750, 750);
INSERT INTO @Cars (CreditFlag, PrivateOfferFlag, ModelName, CashBack, BonusCash) VALUES (0, 0, 'AAA', 1500, 750);
INSERT INTO @Cars (CreditFlag, PrivateOfferFlag, ModelName, CashBack, BonusCash) VALUES (0, 0, 'BBB', 2000, 750);
INSERT INTO @Cars (CreditFlag, PrivateOfferFlag, ModelName, CashBack, BonusCash) VALUES (1, 0, 'CCC', 3000, 750);
INSERT INTO @Cars (CreditFlag, PrivateOfferFlag, ModelName, CashBack, BonusCash) VALUES (0, 0, 'DDD', 3000, 750);
INSERT INTO @Cars (CreditFlag, PrivateOfferFlag, ModelName, CashBack, BonusCash) VALUES (0, 1, 'AAA', 750, 750);

SELECT
    *
FROM        @Cars c1
WHERE       ID = 
            (
                SELECT
                    TOP 1 ID
                FROM        @Cars c2
                WHERE       c2.ModelName = c1.ModelName
                AND         c2.CreditFlag = 1
                AND         c2.PrivateOfferFlag = 1
                AND         c2.CashBack > 0
                AND         c2.BonusCash > 0
                ORDER BY    ID
            );
```

You are able to provide any filtration you'd like in the sub-query, and you can specify any ordering you'd like. I added an ID column and just picked the first such column. You could be more sophisticated and sort descending by TotalSavings, for example.